# Geo tracking database design advice needed

Tags: geolocation

I'm starting to design a geo tracking system and I would apreciate any suggestions regarding DB structure. Database should log points, directions, speed and track

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about database design, it's usually best to list out the types of **queries** that you will want to perform and how often you will perform them. The table structures will usually fall out of that.

It's hard to recommend a design when you only give a 1 sentence description.

Comment: Ok, that's true, but I hoped to get some advice how it is best to store spatial data

Answer (score 0):

[PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) is pretty popular for that purpose.

Comment: The database I will be using will be MSSQL. It too has support for spatial data. But I'm asking how to design database to be able to store points, paths (connected points), direction, be able to replay path. In other words I need an advice how to design GPS tracking database

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what not to do: don't store all your paths' points in one table as linked lists, ala:

```
pointWithPhoto {
    location: <lat/lng>
    next: <point ID>
    prev: <point ID>
    path: <path ID>
    photo: <photo ID> // a point here is related to other DB entities
}
```

Getting all the points for a path gets very expensive very fast.